VS Code is not working
I try to run vs code for developing something but it's not launched since morning, what's happening?
so I uninstalled it from the snap store and re-installed vs code but it is still not working.
Can anyone has a solution, please let me know.

Try vscodium. snap install codium --classic it's vscode but just open sourced. It should work fine

Does this answer your question? VS Code not launching after incorrect command execution on Ubuntu 22.04

I have this issue too.   First time vscode snap has been so broken.  It starts to launch, flashes up briefly then exits immediately.  Nothing in any logs.  No console warnings.   No idea what's going on.

I fixed it by installing the deb package and forgetting about the snap version which is obviously very broken.

You can revert the snap version by running
sudo snap revert code

If uninstalled then,

Reinstall vscode snap and run the sudo snap revert code, OR
Install the 1.89.1 version by
sudo snap install code --revision 1.89.1


I uninstalled code and now the revert is not possible.

You can reinstall vscode snap and run the above command. Or you can directly install the previous version by sudo snap install code --revision 1.89.1


First completely uninstall VScode using snap commands.
sudo snap remove code


Then go the given link and download the package according to you latest distro "https://code.visualstudio.com/download".

After the file get downloaded, use following command in the terminal:
cd Downloads/
sudo dpkg -i [package name]



Note: package name should be replaced by the file name.

Try to download the deb package and then install it. I also have had problems with the snap vs code for a week, but the deb one just works fine.
If you insist on using the snap version, this should do the trick, but be aware it might be very slow, so your best option is to stick with the deb one.
code --in-process-gpu

Codium should also work, but that isn't a response to the asked question....
